# w2ui.grid get data with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

I want to implement w2ui grid and get data from server with parameter.I try to this way but ID posted null so what i am missing here?

```
           function databindSquadMembers(ID) {       
           $('#myGrid2').w2grid({
               name: 'myGrid2',
               url: 'member/Find',
               method: 'GET', 
               show: {
                   toolbar: true,
               },
               columns: [
                   { field: 'PersonalCode', caption: 'PCode'},
                   { field: 'FullName', caption: 'fName'},
               ],             
               postData: {
                   ID: ID,
               },
           });
       }
```

Even if i try to this again ID is showing on controller null

```
postData: {
           ID: 'ID', //or ID:'123'
          },
```

And here is the server side;

```
public JsonResult Find(string ID)  {
 Squad squad = SquadFinder.FindByID(ID);
 IEnumerable members = squad.Members.Cast<SquadMember>()
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    id = ID,
                    PersonalCode = p.Employee.Code,
                    FullName = p.FullName,
                    Email = (null != p.Employee ? p.Employee.Email : "")
                });
return Json(members, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I miss the add;

```
 w2utils.settings.dataType = 'JSON',
```

Now it is working corretly.